# How to shift in tikz scope relatively to an object + offset?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do you shift `(0,0)` to something like: `(MYBOX.west)++(0.1,0)`?

Here is a MnWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[rectangle, draw] at (0,0) (MYBOX) {Something};
        \begin{scope}[shift={$(MYBOX.east) + (0.1,0)$}]
            \draw[black] (0,0) -- ++(0, -1);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need a special tikzlibrary for using $?

Comment: Of course :) I still get this error: ! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.

Comment: Sure. Just a sec. I'm using TikzEdt for building the figure. Let ma reconstruct the preamble.

Comment: You can do `shift=(MYBOX.east), shift={(.1,0)}`. Though be aware, that `shift` does not shift the origin to the specified point but the whole coordinate system about that vector.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use syntax `shift={($(MYBOX.west)+(0.1,0)$)}` (which requires loading the `calc` library using `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`) for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[rectangle, draw] at (0,0) (MYBOX) {Something};
        \begin{scope}[shift={($(MYBOX.east) + (0.1,0)$)}]
            \draw[black] (0,0) -- ++(0, -1);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```